# Evaluate the maximum of: $A = \sin A\cdot\sin ^2 B\cdot \sin ^3 C$

Tags: trigonometry

Given a triangle ABC. Evaluate the maximum of:
$A = \sin A\cdot\sin ^2 B\cdot \sin ^3 C$

Comment: Did you really mean $A = \sin A.{\sin ^2}B.{\sin ^3}C$ or it should be some other function of $(A,B,C)?$

Comment: Are you familiar with the partial derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let 
$$f(A,B,C)=\ln{\sin{A}}+2\ln{\sin{B}}+3\ln{\sin{C}}+\lambda (A+B+C-\pi)$$
then 
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial A}=\cot{A}-\lambda=0\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial B}=2\cot{B}-\lambda=0\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial C}=3\cot{C}-\lambda=0
\end{cases}$$
so
$$\cot{A}:\cot{B}:\cot{C}=1:2:3$$
and use
$$\tan{A}+\tan{B}+\tan{C}=\tan{A}\tan{B}\tan{C}$$
we have
$$\dfrac{1}{k}+\dfrac{1}{2k}+\dfrac{1}{3k}=\dfrac{1}{6k^3}$$
$$\Longrightarrow k^2=\dfrac{1}{11}$$

and use $$\sin{x}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\tan^2{x}}{1+\tan^2{x}}}$$
so
$$\sin{A}=\sqrt{\dfrac{11}{12}},\sin{B}=\sqrt{\dfrac{11}{15}},\sin{C}=\sqrt{\dfrac{11}{20}}$$
so
$$\sin{A}\sin^2{B}\sin^3{C}\le\sqrt{\dfrac{11}{12}}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{11}{15}}\right)^2\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{11}{20}}\right)^3=\dfrac{11^4}{60\sqrt{15}}$$

and we must
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial A^2}|_{\tan^2{A}=11}=-\csc^2{A}_{\tan^2{A}=11}=-\dfrac{12}{11}\\
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial B^2}|_{\tan^2{B}=\dfrac{11}{4}}=-4\csc^2{B}_{\tan^2{B}=\dfrac{11}{4}}=-\dfrac{20}{11}\\
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial C^2}|_{\tan^2{B}=\dfrac{11}{4}}=-9\csc^2{C}_{\tan^2{C}=\dfrac{11}{9}}=-\dfrac{180}{11}\\
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial AB}=0\\
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial BC}=0\\
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial AC}=0
\end{cases}$$
Then the Hessian Matrix
$$H=\begin{vmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial A^2}& \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial AB}&\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial AC}\\
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial BA}&\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial B^2}&\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial BC}\\
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial CA}&\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial CB}&\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial C^2}
\end{vmatrix}=(-\dfrac{12}{11})(-\dfrac{20}{11})(-\dfrac{180}{11})< 0$$

Comment: I don't understand =.=

Comment: I think OP is looking for a trigonometric solution considering it's trig homework, and they likely have not taken any calculus yet.